# WP get all posts from multiple combined category (Advanced)

Tags: php, wordpress

hello i want to get all available posts from multiple category combination.

so my WP_Query Args would be like

```
$args = array(
'category_name' => 'slug_1+slug_2,slug_1+slug3'
);
```

But this does not work.

So the combination would be: get me all the posts from (cat1 and cat2) or (cat1 and cat3) in one query, because i need pagination.

**UPDATE 1**

To bee more specific i have a filter for the post to filter the categories that they have
you can select multiple categories.
the posts all have a default category assigned ex: Job Openings
and in the filter I select another/multiple categories witch are also assigned to the posts.

so :

```
$args1 = array(
    'category_name' => 'slug_1+slug_2'
);
// or
$args2 = array(
    'category_name' => 'slug_1+slug_3'
);
//final arg would be the two combined with and or separator ','
$args_final = array(
    'category_name' => '$args1,$args2'
);
```

how is this possible using one wp_Query args.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'cat1,cat2' ) );
```

> [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)

**UPDATE**

I hope merging two separate WP query result will solve this. Try something like below

```
$query1 = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => 'slug_1+slug_2' ));
$query2 = new WP_Query(array( 'category_name' => 'slug_1+slug_3' ));

$getId = array_merge($query1->posts,$query2->posts);

$finalQuery = new WP_Query(array('post__in' => $getId));
```

Comment: yes i know.... how to do a separate (cat1 and cat 2) query and a separate (cat1 or cat2) but i want them combined as it is in my example

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your WP query like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'category_name=staff,news' );
```

or make the query with category id:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=2,6,17,38' );
```

Have a look over the following link, it must help you: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: yes i know.... how to do a separate (cat1 and cat 2) query and a separate (cat1 or cat2) but i want them combined as it is in my example

i already read documentation. but i do not know how to combine the 2 types of query.